# Working with ESRI WKT Spatial Reference in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, well-known-text

I have been practising [ArcGIS in JavaScript](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/) (for WMS layers ) and have always faced numerical values of `SpatialReference` like `wkid: 102100`, but now I faced in this format:

```
'PROJCS["NAD_1983_HARN_StatePlane_Oregon_North_FIPS_3601",' + 
'GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983_HARN",DATUM["D_North_American_1983_HARN",' +
'SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]]' +
'PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],' +
'UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],' +
'PARAMETER["False_Easting",8202099.737532808],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],' +
'PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-120.5],' +
'PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",44.33333333333334],' +
'PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",46.0],' +
'PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",43.66666666666666],UNIT["Foot",0.3048]]'
```

I came across  [the explanation of the `wkt`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/spatialreference-amd.html#wkt) usage but do not know how to use it together with `extent`. Is there any correct syntax / solution / tutorial I could learn from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string you've pasted is a WKT projection information. This can be [converted into an EPSG code](http://prj2epsg.org/search) if you would like to, but you can [use it directly](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/spatialreference-amd.html#spatialreference3) to construct a `SpatialReference` object in Esri JavaScript API.

```
require([
  "esri/SpatialReference", ... 
], function(SpatialReference, ... ) {
  var sr = new SpatialReference('GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
    SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]'
  );
  ...
});
```

The `Extent` object can be then [constructed](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/extent-amd.html) using the `SpatialReference` object you've created.

Comment: you mean I have to write in a:
  `require([ 'esri/SpatialReference', ''esri/geometry/Extent', ...
  ], function (SpatialReference, ...)

  // define map
  // define layers 
  var sr = new SpatialReference('GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
    SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]'
  );
  var resourceInfo = {
        var extent = new Extent(-126.40869140625, 31.025390625, -109.66552734375, 41.5283203125,{wkt: sr
        }),
        layerInfos: [...]
      };
      `
format?

Comment: Look at the `Extent` constructor information - it has examples on how to specify the spatial reference; you would be supplying `{"spatialReference": sr}`

Comment: Thank you! Found another way with no definition of extent and sr values. But thank you -- yours was helpful.